# Loopback customize remote method error callback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have a little problems with loopback models. I have various models with remote method attacked. All methods respond with own callback function. 
My problem start when I put error object in the callback function.
For example:

```
 promise()
        .then(promiseResult => sencondPromise())
        .then(promiseResult => cb(null, promiseResult))
        .catch(err => cb({"status" : 400, "message" : "Response test"}, null));
```

There aren't problems when triggered positive callback. But when triggered negative callback:

```
cb({"status" : 400, "message" : "Response test"}, null));
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Response test"
  }
}
```

Why status field it's changed to statusCode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is that a problem? What you exactly need to do?

Comment: For me this response it's a problem, because I must use another type to error response.
Eg:
`{
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Response test"
  }
}`
It's possible to change the default parameter 'statusCode' to 'status' ?

Comment: This is official error object loopback send back to clients. If you want to custom error object you need to create your own

Answer (score 2):

For creating your own error handler :

1) Remove `strong-error-handler` from `middleware.json`

2) Create `config.local.js` and put below code there:

```
function errorConverter(options){
  return function(err, req, res, next){
    //check err and create your custom error object
    var customErr = {};
    next(customErr);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  remoting: {
    errorHandler: {
      handler: errorConverter()
    }
  }
};
```